# Youtube API - Subscriptions list returns different number of total results in set

Tags: google-api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to get the complete list of my subscriptions. I've tried 3 methods, all of them returns different amount of subscriptions and I don't know what to do :)

1: Using [Subscriptions: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list) with channel ID:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet&channelId=MY_CHANNEL_ID&maxResults=50&key=MY_API_KEY

"totalResults" is 942

2: Using [Subscriptions: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list) with "mine" flag. the "totalResult" field is 991.
Where do 49 subscriptions appear from?

3: Open browser in incognite mode, go to
https://www.youtube.com/channel/MY_CHANNEL_ID

Click on "Channels" tab, scroll down to the end of the subscriptions list, open console and type something like that
`document.querySelectorAll("#contents #items > *").length`
I see 1039. Where do another 48 subscriptions come from?

And the 1039 seems to be the most accurace number - I have 6 subscriptions in a row and the last row has only 1 item. 173*6+1 = 1039

So the questions is - how do I get all the 1039 subscriptions by API? And why does it return wrong amount of subscriptions?

Answer (score 0):

You are using [Subscriptions: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list) and shouldn't have such kind of bugs with `totalResults` however maybe there is a YouTube Data API v3 endpoint bug as documented in [Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) `totalResults` is:

> **integer**
>
> The total number of results in the result set. Please note that the value is an approximation and may not represent an exact value. In addition, the maximum value is 1,000,000.
>
> You should not use this value to create pagination links. Instead, use the **nextPageToken** and **prevPageToken** property values to determine whether to show pagination links.

So I would recommend you to enumerate all subscriptions you have with the different methods you explained and so count on your own by using `nextPageToken`.